# How to make a ViewModelFactory with an id parameter in its constructor injectable?

Tags: android, dagger, android-viewmodel

I'm using ViewModel in Android with Dagger to manage dependencies. My ViewModel will get an id from MainActivity while creating. So I have These codes here:

In Activity:

```
@inject ViewModelProviderFactory mViewModelFactory;
ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

My Factory provider:

```
public class ViewModelProviderFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private int id;

    @inject
    public ViewModelProviderFactory(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        return new MyViewModel(id);
    }    
}
```

For work this I need to add a parameter to my Module:

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {
    int id;
    public MainActivityModule(int id){ 
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Provides
    ViewModelProvider.Factory mainViewModelProvider() {
        return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(id);
    }
}
```

Or I can do it directly in component and made it abstract.
In new Dagger, I can use Dagger class to make activity or fragment component. So I should create subcomponent for each activity and a Builder and tones of other codes which I should write.

Is there any simple and better way to prevent these extra codes or it's better I made my Factory by calling just a new factory in the activity like this?:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ViewModelProviderFactory(id)).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion calling `new ViewModelProviderFactory(id)` from the `Activity` is much simpler solution. Hovewer, I'd not use the constructor **directly** from the `Activity`. Instead I'd create the factory (yes, factory of factory...), which I'd inject into `Activity`.

Here is an example:

```
class FactoryOfFactory {

    @Inject
    FactoryOfFactory() {}

    ViewModelProvider.Factory create(int id) {
        // ViewModelProviderFactory can now by just an anonymous class
        return new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
                return (T) new MyViewModel(id);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    FactoryOfFactory factoryOfFactory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final int id = 123;
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, factoryOfFactory.create(id)).get(MyViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

This method has also the following solution: if `MyViewModel` needs another dependencies (which are not provided by the `Activity`), we can add them very easily (without modifying `Activity`):

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    MyViewModel(int id, AnotherDependency anotherDependency) { }
}

class FactoryOfFactory {

    private final AnotherDependency anotherDependency; // added

    @Inject
    FactoryOfFactory(final AnotherDependency anotherDependency) {  // modified
        this.anotherDependency = anotherDependency; // added
    }

    ViewModelProvider.Factory create(int id) {
        // ViewModelProviderFactory can now by just an anonymous class
        return new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
                return (T) new MyViewModel(id, anotherDependency);  // modified
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And, of course, I believe that a name better than `FactoryOfFactory` exist ;)